# appropriate directory to store service/module configuration file samplee

Tags: repo

I plan to add a new directory "samples" to our company code repo, it is to store all the configuration file sample.
The pro is whenever we run into the code related about one file read/write, we can skip it and directory go to check file sample. there we can quickly have a good idea of  file schema and content.
I believe it can save some code-reading efforts.

How do you think this plan? and where this "samples" directory should be? I am thinking just add to top level in our repo

thanks